# Responsive image gallery and empty spaces with masonry

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-masonry

I'm trying to do a responsive image gallery with masonry jquery plugin.
I read many article, including in this forum, but it doesn't work. Many blank spaces appears in the gallery.

I'm trying with Jquery Masonry and a simple css and html

`.flow { width: 95%; height: auto; min-height: 500px; margin: 0 auto}
.item {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}`

`

```
<div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.smartynet.com.br/flampic/img/1small.jpg" />
</div>

<div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.smartynet.com.br/flampic/img/2small.jpg" />
</div>
    </div>
```

I created this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eSMXf/).

I'm trying to build a gallery like flickr. There is any other best way?
Please someone could help me?

Answer (score -1):

can you just try the Flex Slider for responsive image gallery
http://flexslider.woothemes.com/ or try
http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/
or 
http://fancybox.net/

Comment: It doesn't what i'm lokking for... :(